# Please help get a hold lifted from a question

Tags: support

I made the mistake of using the word "resident" in my original question, and not being clear enough of my role in the project/situation. The topic has been placed on HOLD, and I am trying to get the HOLD lifted. Here is the [reworded question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34800/can-a-wifi-repeater-be-used-to-hijack-an-access-point)

As I have pointed out to the moderator, I am supporting management of a network in a place of business that is using non-consumer grade equipment. The RV park I am supporting collects money from customers in exchange for goods and services. I own a small business and have received  compensation from this RV park for services provided, including network engineering. The network in question is owned by the RV Park which is providing a service to the customers. At least one person has voted up my question.

I'm not asking for a rule change. I'm asking for a clearer process to get a hold lifted when the requirements of a post have been met.

Thank you.

Comment: The process is that you edited the question, and it automatically comes up for a reopen vote. If people vote to reopen the question, then it will be reopened.

Comment: Please tell me who these people are. And what weight is applied, if any, from the up vote to the question itself?

Comment: The up vote has no effect. There are review queues for various types of votes, and the people with enough reputation to vote can look in the queues and vote to reopen a question.

Comment: How long does this process take? And when does the user know it is complete? And does this mean that the moderator who placed the hold cannot lift it?